# Snakemake scatter-gather with wildcard AmbiguousRuleException

Tags: python, wildcard, bioinformatics, snakemake

My problem is when using Snakemake scatter-gather feature the documentation is basic and i modified my code according to mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64898553/19589226):

```py
rule fastq_fasta:
    input:rules.trimmomatic.output.out_file
    output:"data/trimmed/{sample}.fasta"
    shell:"sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' {input} > {output}"

rule split:
    input:
        "data/trimmed/{sample}.fasta"
    params:
        scatter_count=config["scatter_count"],
        scatter_item = lambda wildcards: wildcards.scatteritem
    output:
        temp(scatter.split("data/trimmed/{{sample}}_{scatteritem}.fasta"))
    script:
        "scripts/split_files.py"
        
rule process:
    input:"data/trimmed/{sample}_{scatteritem}.fasta"
    output:"data/processed/{sample}_{scatteritem}.csv"
    script:
        "scripts/process.py"

rule gather:
    input:
        gather.split("data/processed/{{sample}}_{scatteritem}.csv")
    output:
        "data/processed/{sample}.csv"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

I added wildcard option but, I got:

```
AmbiguousRuleException: Rules fastq_to_fasta(which is previous rule) and split are ambiguous for the file data/trimmed/Ornek_411-of-81-of-81-of-81-of-81-of-81-of-81-of-81-of-81-of-8.fasta
```

I tried lots of things but either rules are not calling or take `AmbiguousRuleException`. What am i missing, can someone help?

Comment: I think it's better to post this question in https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AmmarSabirCheema In general questions about snakemake are better suited to SO rather than bioinformatics.stackexchange.com since snakemake a general workflow manager. This question is related to bioinformatics but it is still general software development - so I think it's fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ambiguity in terms of which rule should generate the specific file. An easy fix (if feasible) is to use a different path for scattered items:

```py
rule split:
    input:
        "data/trimmed/{sample}.fasta"
    params:
        scatter_count=config["scatter_count"],
        scatter_item = lambda wildcards: wildcards.scatteritem
    output:
        temp(scatter.split("data/trimmed_scatter/{{sample}}_{scatteritem}.fasta"))
    script:
        "scripts/split_files.py"
        
rule process:
    input:"data/trimmed_scatter/{sample}_{scatteritem}.fasta"
    output:"data/processed/{sample}_{scatteritem}.csv"
    script:
        "scripts/process.py"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, ambiguity solved with removing this line in params: scatter_item = lambda wildcards: wildcards.scatteritem.

Comment: That's great, but I'm also not sure why `params` would affect this... perhaps you can post an answer also.

Comment: soory i miss wrote, ambiguity solved with your suggestion but i also got new error and removing that param line it solved issue. The error because i couldn't pass also scatteritem as a wildcard instead of that i pass sample name as wildcard. In python file all possible outputs comes with scatteritem named so i fetch it from there. The reason is why i did like that. i divided file with condition so.

Comment: Aaah, got it, great!